# Searching / Copying specific content from an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have `10% Current / 2% PIK Senior Secured Debt (Maturity- September 19, 2019)` in a cell, and I want to extract just the date, in this case `September 19, 2019`, and copy that over into a different cell.

I can search the cell for the months (`January`, `February`... etc) but is there a way to copy the next ~8 characters to complete the date?

Comment: Google `instr` and `mid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in cell **A1**, in another cell:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("- ",A1)+2,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("- ",A1)-2)
```

[image]

This assumes that there is a *dash space* before the date and a close parens after the date.

**EDIT#1:**

I am not sure I understand, but to make a formula that will work with both *dash space* and just *dash*:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("- ",A1)),MID(A1,FIND("- ",A1)+2,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("- ",A1)-2),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

[image]

But the formula is rapidly losing its beauty.

Comment: Gary - I edited mine right as you posted your answer. They are similar, so didn't want you to think I was copy-catting :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  As I commented - the approach is pretty standard......find the left encapsulator.........find the right encapsulator.........subtract..............

Comment: I like this one as well, however some of the data has hyphens while others have m dashes... Is there a way to search for either / or  ?

Comment: @RafaelBucciarelli  I would need to see specific examples.

Comment: For example, the sample you used had `10% Current / 2% PIK Secured Debt (Maturity- September 19, 2019)` while the next entry is `10% Current / 2% PIK Secured Debt (Maturity—September 19, 2019)`. I should be able to adjust the FIND criteria to catch both of these cases, right?

Comment: @RafaelBucciarelli.......so some records have *dash space* and other records do not have the *space* ??

Comment: Exactly. (Does the _dash_ being different sizes not matter?)

Comment: He is talking about the `--` or char(151) versus the `-` or char(45). Sometimes it is one and not the other.

Comment: @RafaelBucciarelli  Perhaps my **EDIT#1** is what you need *(maybe not)*

Comment: @ScottCraner  Whatever the criteria, the approach would be the same.......use something like `=ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(),A1))` to determine which `=MID()` formula to pick

Comment: I know, I was just trying to help clarify that it was not `- Sept..` or `-Sept..` that it was the double dash.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you.............more examples in the original question would have helped.

Comment: back to the space or not the space, couldn't you just search on the `-` and use `TRIM()` as a wrapper to get rid of the space if it is there?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is in cell E2, this formula will work for any month so long as the "-" is always after Maturity and close parenthesis after date.

```
=MID(E2,FIND("-",E2)+2,FIND(")",E2,FIND("-",E2)+2)-1-FIND("-",E2)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always at the end and in the same format this will pull the last three "words"

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AP7," ",""))-2)),999),LEN(MID(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-2)),999))-1)
```